# ¿Cómo mostrar correctamente Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, html5, materialize

Estoy usando Materialize CSS  y más específicamente quiero usar el [Datepicker](http://materializecss.com/forms.html#date-picker) para un formulario, trato de integrarlo con Django pero no se me muestra de la forma correcta, por lo que pasé a probarlo de la forma rudimentaria.

Este es el código HTML y tengo las librerías JS y CSS vinculadas en mi HTML.

```
<form class="col s12">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <label for="birthdate" class="">Birthdate</label>
       <input id="birthdate" type="date" class="datepicker">
    </div>
</form>
```

Y el JS está así (tambíen cargado al HTML)

```
 $('.datepicker').pickadate({
    selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
    selectYears: 15 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
  });
```

Pero se me muestra así. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, el problema es el ancho o el formato?

Comment: Parece un problema de conflictos de estilos. Se puede deducir por el aspecto del input, hay uno sobrepuesto. ¿Sucede solo con el datepicker o también con otros controles?

Comment: @AlfredoCebrián Resulta que el Script JS lo ponía un un archivo aparte y no lo reconocía. La solución fue poner el script dentro del HTML (al final del todo) y ya funcionó (Y).

Comment: @GustavoGarcía La solución fue poner el script dentro del HTML (al final del todo) y ya funcionó (Y).

Answer (score 2):

La solución fue poner el script dentro del HTML (al final del todo) y ya funcionó (Y).

Al parecer al llamarlo desde un archivo externo (archiv.js) no lo reconoce, por eso debe estar dentro del HTML que está usando el DatePicker.

Answer (score 0):

En realidad, el problema está en que no diste tiempo al DOM para que se cargue entero antes de tener disponible tu archivo javascript.

Básicamente, tu código **javascript se estaba ejecutando antes que se carguen todos los elementos** de la página. Entonces javascript al no encontrar el elemento `.datepicker` no hizo nada. Y la página al terminar de cargar todos los elementos, no avisa a javascript.

La solución tuya, de colocar javascript al final de la página, funciona, porque para que llegue a cargar esa parte, tiene que haber cargado todo lo anterior.

Sin embargo, una mejor solución es separar javascript en un archivo diferente, y cuando la página esté cargada, recién ejecutar el código javascript. JQuery provee de `$(document).ready()` para avisarle a javascript que todos los elementos de la página ya se cargaron. En tu caso por ejemplo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datepicker').pickadate({
        selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
        selectYears: 15 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    });
});
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar, así lo tenía en un archivo externo y no andaba.

Comment: Pero en el archivo externo, ¿hiciste que el código se ejecute recién cuando la página esté totalmente cargada? O sea, dentro de `$(document).ready(function() { /* Todo tu código */ });`

Comment: Claro, aquí lo dejo.

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.button-collapse').sideNav();
  $('select').material_select();
  $(".dropdown-button").dropdown({
    belowOrigin: true, // Displays dropdown below the button
    hover: true, // Activate on hover
  });
});

Comment: Dentro de ese código que pasaste nunca mencionaste al `.datepicker`. Pero suponiendo que sí lo probaste, estabas seguro que se estaba relacionando bien tu archivo js con tu html? Por ejemplo, escribiendo dentro del mismo un "alert("Hola mundo");"??? No es que esté mal en sí JS dentro de un HTML, sino, que realizando un archivo JS, con código como ese, te permitiría evitar duplicar mucho código (Entre más beneficios).

Comment: Si, entiendo que es la mejor manera, pero puede probarlo por su propia cuenta. Intenté haciendo un simple alert y ni eso me ejecutaba.

Comment: Si no te estaba ejecutando el simple alert, es porque no estabas enlazando bien tu archivo js con tu html. Cuando hacés f12 (En chrome) te debe haber tirado un error diciendo que no se podía encontrar el archivo js que habías puesto en tu html. Probablemente por problemas con las rutas relativas.

Answer (score 0):

Debes cambiar tipo de dato del `input` de `date` a `text`. Por alguna razón en *Firefox* no reconoce el `type="date"`.

Answer (score -1):

Escribe esta linea en el fichero JavaScript, para que actualice el materialize:

```
Materialize.updateTextFields();
```